# SQL syntax error while creating table in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

While creating a table in Mariadb with this code

```
CREATE TABLE classes(
    ClassID SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY,
    Grade TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    Subject VARCHAR(20),
    YearTaught YEAR
);
```

I got this error.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
> Grade TINYINT UNSIGNED,
> Subject VARCHAR(20),
> YearTaught YEAR
> )' at line 2

And I don't know what's wrong with the syntax. Thank you.

Comment: `ClassID SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY` Also, names are case-insensitive, it is more common to use snake case instead of camel case. year_taught instead of YearTaught

Comment: glad to hear that it helped. If that solved your problem, then that comment should have been an answer, I will re-post it. if it helped you consider [marking it accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or [up-voting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the keyword `KEY` on your statement, update

```sql
ClassID SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY,
```

to

```sql
ClassID SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
```

You could use `KEY` instead of `PRIMARY KEY`, but not just `PRIMARY`:

> Use PRIMARY KEY (or just KEY) to make a column a primary key. A primary key is a special type of a unique key. There can be at most one primary key per table, and it is implicitly NOT NULL.

The [documentation is here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#primary-key-column-option).